# How to extend class that is inside a loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've got an swf loaded externally to my app with loader component. It is loaded to the Application Domain of my loader. I've got a class in that swf wich I would like to extend and override some functions from it. Is it possible somehow? 
Here is some code to explain what I want(of course, it is fully incorrect and wold not work):

```
public var ClassFromLoadedSwf:Class = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition("path.to.needed.class") as Class;
public class MyClass extends ClassFromLoadedSwf
{
    override protected function initMovie() : void
    {
         //function logic goes here
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answers and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you can't. Basically you don't understand the meaning of `ApplicationDomain`. Using a loader and Applicaiton Domain you just merge some code to your SWF in Runtime. Before it reaches the Runtime state, it can't be accessed. So at the Compile time you can't do what you're trying to do now. But you can try to use SWC instead of SWF. You just include it in your Project Library and that's all. You'll be able to access all the classes at compile time. Try reading this [Article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/combine-swfs-with-swcs.html). It will help you understand the meaning of SWCs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've alreay figured out that i can't do this, but I can implement my own class with same package path and then loaded swf will use it instead of using the class, that it has. Unfortunatelly I can not modify or access a code of a loaded swf, while it is loading from a remote server...

Comment: You could try writing an Interface that your class from the other swf will extend and use that Interface as the data type where you need your class from other swf.